# Get translation from Google Translate API as PHP variable

Tags: php, rest, google-translate

I am trying to get translated text from Google Translate REST API in PHP. Response is in JSON format and it looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "translated text which I want to get",
        "detectedSourceLanguage": "en"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I wonder how can I extract it as a PHP variable? My current code is that but it is not working:

```
$ownwords = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['ownwords']);

$geoownwordsapiurl = "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=SOMEVALIDAPIKEY&q={$ownwords}&target=en";

$geoownwords = json_decode(file_get_contents($geoownwordsapiurl), true);

foreach ($geoownwords as $geoownword) {
    $translatedwords = $geoownword['data']['translations']['translatedText'];
}

echo $translatedwords;
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it does not work" ? do you get an error ? wrong result ? no result ?

Comment: @ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ not a single error. When I run a test PHP file it is blank

Comment: Skip the foreach. You foreach an array but still use direct path.

Comment: @Andreas So how can I skip foreach?

Comment: Just delete the line starting with foreach, and the line `}`. Then replace geoownword with geoownword**s**

Comment: @Andreas Does not works. Result is empty

Comment: It works. I just forgot the [0]. But the answer below works.https://3v4l.org/pJBG4

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do in the loop (I just build a string of all of them below), but you need to loop `translations`, assuming there can be more than one:

```
$translatedwords = '';

foreach($geoownwords['data']['translations'] as $geoownword) {
    $translatedwords .= $geoownword['translatedText'];
}
echo $translatedwords;
```

If there will be only one:

```
echo $geoownwords['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
```

Comment: Now echo is "Array" and nothing more. Just Array